# does Protobuf-net has plans to include validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, protobuf-net

Is there a way to incorporate something like Data Annotations to protobuf-net? I found this using fluentvalidation https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/05/18/grpc-asp-net-core-3-1-model-validation/

But I would like something I can use the attributes I define in the model, like Required, StringLength, etc?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. Validation isn't a feature of protobuf, so protobuf-net doesn't provide it itself. However, you can add before/after serialize/deserialize callbacks, in which you could add any manual validation you like.